# Exacutable looks like a file in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: source-code

I am compiling a FORTRAN code using gfortran (gfortram -o code.f code) and preparing an executable (code). It is compiled but the executable (code) looks like a file.
How to solve this problem.

[image: picture]

Comment: Are you sure you're using it correctly; the `-o` option is where to output the compiled code & it's normally not given a `code.f` type of name, that's usually used for the input you've used the name `code` for.... ie. `[-o outfile] infile...` is from `man gfortran`; you appear to have file order reversed.

Comment: I have also tried this way.. but the problem is same. it is compiled and executable say output is working using ./output. but this executable looks like a file.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: shared for your consideration

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source is called `source.f` and the output is `output`, the syntax is

```
gfortran -o output source.f
```

Comment: I have also tried this way.. but the problem is same. it is compiled and executable say output is working using ./output. but this executable looks like a file.